# BeautifulSoup and Python Lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am having a hard time understanding this code.

I would like to extract `HTML` comments using `BeautifulSoup` and `Python3`.

Given:

```
html = '''
       <!-- Python is awesome -->
       <!-- Lambda is confusing -->
       <title>I don't grok it</title>
       '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

I searched for solutions and most people said:

```
comments = soup.find_all(text= lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))
```

Which in my case would result in:

```
[' Python is awesome ', ' Lambda is confusing ']
```

This is what I understand:

- `isinstance` asks if `text` is an instance of `Comment` and returns a boolean.
- I sort of understand `lambda`. Takes `text` as an argument and evaluates the `isinstance` expression.
- You can pass a function to `find_all`

This is what I do not understand:

- What is `text` in `text=`?
- What is `text` in `lambda text`?
- What argument from `html` is passed into `lambda text`
- `soup.text` returns `I don't grok it`. Why is `lambda text` passing `<!-- Python is awesome -->` as an argument?

Comment: It really sounds like you need a basic Python tutorial, followed by a detailed reading of the relevant beautifulsoup docs. The docs are pretty hard to understand if you do not have a working knowledge of basic Python constructs. I am telling you this because even the explanations you get here will not help you as much as they ought until you understand the underlying concepts. While jumping head first into a subject is indeed a good way to learn, fundamentals are also very important.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you please clarify what fundamentals I need? I think I am strong with basic Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Summary

`.find_all()` goes through each line and tries to match `text='<our_text>`. Instead of an actual string *(like in the example down)* `'<our_text>'` is a **lambda** function that basically has a condition.

***I'll explain each part of this question.***

## `text=`

```
html = '''
       <!--Python is awesome-->
       <!--Lambda is confusing-->
       <title>I don't grok it</title>
       '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

`print(soup.find_all(text='Python is awesome'))`

Output:

> ['Python is awesome']

Here `text=` is only a **parameter** (i.e. argument) where we can pass a regex or **another function** or a **variable** or `'string'`. It just happened to be a **lambda** in our case. We'll explain next what the lambda does.

## `Lambda`

This **lambda** function takes in `text` variable as input.

*We automatically feed the text of each line into the lambda-func with `.find_all`*

```
lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)
```

And the `isinstance` checks if the first arg. `text` is `Comment` it either returns **True** OR **False**. Example: `some_var = 'Ey man'` then I do `isisntance(some_var, str)` -> **True**. *It's a string (str)*.

Next, we combine both of these.

`soup.find_all(text= lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))`

1. `soup.find_all` - goes through each line `<--Python is awesome..`, `<--Lambda..` `<title>I..`
2. We have a condition within the `.find_all(<the_condition>)` and keep the lines that fulfill that condition
3. The condition in our case is,

   3.1. Firstly we don't check everything only the clear, plain English text and **inside tags**, and/or whatever **string** there is. That's `text=`

   3.2. The text also has a condition, it doesn't take any text, only if a **lambda function** returns True, i.e. fulfills the condition of the **lambda**.

   3.3. The lambda **condition** is that it has to be an instance of `Comment` meaning only if it's a **Comment** it will return **True**.

*Only and only if all these conditions are met we take that **line** and store it.*

Comment: @tomorodonez I have explained it in great detail in my answer, let me know if I should clarify anything else. I would also appreciate edits (suggestions or other ways) to my answer if it's going to improve it. 
Anything, readability -- functionality -- effectivness.

Comment: Thanks for the details. I think the only change is that after digging into the BS4 docs. It said that the `text` argument was replaced by `string`. Then the `text` variable inside `lambda` could be anything. Such as: `soup.find_all(string= lambda html_comment: isinstance(html_comment, Comment))`. Thanks.

Comment: `text` is still supported. Yes exactly, awesome understanding, thank you too for going through the effort of looking into the `docs`, you made an educated and formidable question and without any research, it'd be hard for anyone to explain all of this.  
Take care!

Answer (score 2):

> What is text in text=?

A keyword argument to the find_all function

> What is text in lambda text?

The parameter for the function, same as

```
def <name>(text)...
```

> What argument from html is passed into lambda text

that would be up to you,  in the sample the variable Comments refers to the text to parse.

> soup.text returns I don't grok it. Why is lambda text passing  as an argument?

that's just an example to be replaced with real HTML

Comment: Thanks. Can you please clarify? I know text= is a keyword argument. But what is its value? I know lambda text is the same as def name(text). But what is the value of text there?. There is no variable Comments. Above `comments` is refer to a list of results and not as the text to parse. What do you mean to be replaced with real HTML? Thanks.

Comment: The value is the the lambda (a function definition, in other words).  The value of text in the lambda definition is set at run time, when it is called by find_all. Comment is the type being tested in isinstance.  The sample code you posted has sample html, in the real world it will be, well, real!  Like the html for this page you are looking at, right now.